# DataFrame columns from objects to float

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-structures, type-conversion, transformation

i´m just starting with python and maybe I´m asking something that's already been answered, but none of the solutions I found fixes my problem.

So I have a csv file saved via excel(if that even matters). It looks something like this

```
Dates              Open     Close    
29.04.2019 18:00   1,1186   1,1186
29.04.2019 18:01   1,1186   1,1187
29.04.2019 18:02   1,1187   1,1186
29.04.2019 18:03   1,1188   1,1189
```

But columns "Open" and Close" are objects and I can't seem change them into floats. I already tried .astype and .to_numeric etc.

any other suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `df['Open'] = df['Open'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

Comment: You should do `df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', thousands=',')`.

Comment: @Suraj Okay, the data type has changed, but now I've got 11186 instead of 1,1186..

Comment: @Quang maybe for specification: the data in the column "Close" is the close price of EUR/USD. So I need the object 1,1186 to be the same number but not as an object but as a float

Comment: oh, then in your case `df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', decimal=',')`?

Comment: yes, I think that's what I need! For some reason the first value is NaN now but as I think that's fine. thanks a lot